# Neither elements in an wordList

Tags: python

I have such a function:

```
def ladderLength(self, beginWord, endWord, wordList):
    """
    :type beginWord: str
    :type endWord: str
    :type wordList: List[str]
    :rtype: int
    """
    if (endWord not in wordList) or (beginWord not in wordList):
        return 0
```

The multiple bool operations are cumbersome.

```
    if (endWord not in wordList) or (beginWord not in wordList):
        return 0
```

How could reduce it to be clear and concise?

Comment: What do you return if the condition is not met?

Comment: They are not cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all your `if`-block does is this:

```
  if (endWord not in wordList) or (beginWord not in wordList):
    return 0
  else:  # <- I am assuming this, see Note 1
    return 1
```

then you can replace the whole thing with:

```
return int(all(x in wordList for x in (endWord, beginWord)))
```

---

> Note 1
>
> Not having an `else` clause is generally perfectly fine but in your case you would have a function that might return `0` or `None` and that is not optimal\recommended. If you can, redesign it as per above.
>
> If not, I wouldn't bother changing the condition. The one you have is very readable and there are no alternatives that are much better. Sure you could do:
>
> ```
> if not all(x in wordList for x in (endWord, beginWord)):
>     return 0
> ```
>
> but that is pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
   if any([x not in wordList for x in [endWord, beginWord]]):
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this function to speed up a bit (`O(log n)` instead of `O(n)`) - consider changing the `wordList` type for `Set[str]`. In this case the function will be:

```
def ladderLength(self, beginWord, endWord, wordList):
    """
    :type beginWord: str
    :type endWord: str
    :type wordList: Set[str]
    :rtype: int
    """
    return int(bool({beginWord, endWord} & wordList))
```